# How does the prototype lookup work in isPrototypeOf on inherited classes?

Tags: javascript

Taking the following code as a starting point:

```js
class SuperKlass {};
class SubKlass extends SuperKlass {};

const superKlass = new SuperKlass();
const subKlass = new SubKlass();

console.log(SuperKlass.isPrototypeOf(SubKlass));
console.log(SuperKlass.prototype.isPrototypeOf(subKlass));
console.log(SuperKlass.prototype.isPrototypeOf(SubKlass.prototype));
// true true true
```

How does the lookup work for each of these? For example, the definition of the [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) states:

> The `isPrototypeOf()` method checks if an object exists in another object's prototype chain.

So for the first one, `SuperKlass.isPrototypeOf(SubKlass)`, `SubKlass` is the object whose prototype chain we are inspecting to find if it exists in `SuperKlass`. So then how does that work exactly? I tried debugging it a big in Chrome dev tools and figured it out on some trial-and-error for the first one:

[image]

When looking up the prototype chain does it use `__proto__` or `.prototype`? And how would it work for the other two?

Comment: "*When looking up the prototype chain does it use `__proto__` or `.prototype`?*" - neither. It uses `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Answer (score -1):

There are two important concepts here to understand [`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) :

1. The prototype chain is traversed via `.__proto__`, not via `.prototype`.
2. If the method call has the form: `Parent.isPrototypeOf(item)`, then we first check to see if `item.__proto__ === Parent`, if it is not then we check to see if `item.__proto__.__proto__ === Parent`, ... all the way until the prototype chain ends (`<...>.__proto__ === null`).

With this we can build a basic function to emulate this method and add in some debugging helpers to see how it works:

```js
function isPrototypeOf(obj, parent) {
    // a function to search the prototype chain of object to see if it's found in parent
    let isFound = false;
    let proto = obj.__proto__;
    while (proto) {
        console.log('Proto: ', proto);
        if (proto === parent) {
            console.log('Found!');
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
        proto = proto.__proto__;
    }
    return isFound;
}


class SuperKlass {};
class SubKlass extends SuperKlass {};
const superKlass = new SuperKlass();
const subKlass = new SubKlass();
console.log(isPrototypeOf(SubKlass, SuperKlass));
console.log(isPrototypeOf(subKlass, SuperKlass.prototype));
console.log(isPrototypeOf(SubKlass.prototype, SuperKlass.prototype));
console.log(isPrototypeOf(SubKlass.prototype, SuperKlass.prototype.prototype)); // this shouldn't be found and will traverse until null
```

Comment: Please do not use the deprecated `.__proto__` getter, which doesn't even exist on all objects

Comment: @Bergi what should be used instead? And what's an example of where that wouldn't work? In the compatibility table, it seems to work everywhere and I've never seen it not work.

Comment: It doesn't work on `Obect.create(null)` or `Object.create(Object.create(null))` or a simple `{["__proto__"]: "oops"}`. As I commented above, you should use `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Comment: What compatibility table did you look at?

Comment: @Bergi got it, thanks for the clarification. So instead of doing `SuperKlass.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype` I should do `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(SuperKlass)) === Object.prototype` ?

Comment: @Bergi this one: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Then surely you've also noticed the three bold red warnings at the top of that very page?

Comment: @Bergi oh yea, of course.